# Are there any advantages/disadvantages to passing a list/dict as a parameter to a function, vs just modifying it directly in the function?

Tags: python

Are there any advatages or disadvantages to doing this

```
listtt =[1]
dicto = {'a':2}

def ffun():
    listtt.append(2)
    dicto['b'] = 3

ffun()
print(listtt)
print(dicto)
```

> [1, 2] 
>   {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

vs this

```
listtt =[1]
dicto = {'a':2}

def ffun(hh, hh2):
    hh.append(2)
    hh2['b'] = 3

ffun(listtt, dicto)
print(listtt)
print(dicto)
```

> [1, 2] 
>   {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

Comment: Passing in objects lets the caller know of 'what might be happening' - hopefully the method-level documentation explains the rest (in *both cases* there is a side-effect). It is thus "better" in many cases; the *caller* is forced to make a relevant choice and thus the operation is more transparent. In this case since the variable is used later on in the caller it only adds code divergence to access the global implicitly in the function. (One might argue the larger issue is not using objects as containers, or mutation in general, and.. digressions.. regardless, *think of the children*.)

Comment: The 2nd function can modify any list/dict you give it, not just ones named `listtt` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hi,

I might be oversimplifying this but passing the dict and list with even a very high volume then what you have there would not cause any issues. Python passes parameters by object reference so there is no memory operation and performance should be same in both cases.
Having said that you still need to reconsider why you want to have global variables in the first place. Kaya has already linked a discussion around global variables in the comments. Worth having a quick read*

Comment: Python *does not use pass by reference*, but your answer is correct otherwise

Comment: I have edited to mention pass by object reference , if you read my answer clearly I mentioned that I am simplifying the answer to meet the needs of what was asked, how python passes and the details are already present in a lot of questions. Thanks

Comment: Note: Performance would actually be worse for globals if the names were referenced repeatedly; global lookups/stores require a `dict` lookup, while function locals (including arguments) are a C-level array lookup that runs significantly faster.

Comment: Simplifying is fine, stating something that is *simply wrong* is another